# Can I call any method in XmlHttpRequest not only GET, POST, PUT

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-apicontroller

**Can I call any method in XmlHttpRequest not only GET, POST, PUT ?**

> ***More Information: ***
>
> > I have Controller named equal = `AccountsController`
> >
> > > In Controller I have method named equal `Connnect(Account acc)`
> > >
> > > > I want call this method from that controller **How ?**

*For example:*

```
var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
xhr.open("CONNECT", "www.any.link/api/Accounts", true);
```

Comment: so what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @epascarello Can I call any method not only GET, POST, PUT ?

Comment: @epascarello i will test but can you answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `HEAD`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS` and `CONNECT`.

For more information you can visit this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

And maybe you find useful this post:

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: Can I use another of these ? for example Can I use ISONLINE method created by me in some Controller ??